# What does a ({ }) in objective-c means?

Tags: objective-c

I encountered the following code in others' project:

```
_titleLabel = ({
        UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        label.numberOfLines = 1;
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f];
        label;
    });
```

See this usage for the first time, what is it about?

Comment: Look's like _titleLabel will have that label.

Comment: This is using the block syntax to offset the scope, so that you can define the labels as you would, possibly multiple different labels, without having to change the name of the inline `UILabel` variable -- making it easier to copy and past the code (is that a good thing?)

Comment: See [Statements and Declarations in Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Comment: @TZHX Nope. A block should start with a ^

Comment: @Mats Yeah you're right. Sorry to find a similar question TAT.